# how to cancel cycle combo box on touch xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I working on a win 8 metrostyle app
I have combo boxes in app.
when I click on combo box with mouse it works normal. it pops up a list and I can scroll 
but when I use touching the items in the combo box keeps rolling. it doesnt stop at top or bottom

is there an attribute for it to cancel??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ComboBox displays repeated Items in Windows 8 Surface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084515/combobox-displays-repeated-items-in-windows-8-surface)

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN forums have an answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/winappswithcsharp/thread/00807f53-8163-409a-ae84-1f30fb1a5238). What you can do is set the items panel for the combobox to override this default behavior.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
<ComboBox>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thank you. This may be obvious but wanted to add just in case: if you currently use the ComboBox.ItemTemplate element for something custom, both the ComboBox.ItemsPanel and ComboBox.ItemTemplate belong side by side with each other in the hierarchy of the .xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on windows 8 metro style applications since the first day it was released. I encountered the very same problem last week, and was unable to fix it. After a while, I uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio 2012 from my development machine, and the problem is automatically fixed.

You can give it a try.