# ComboBox displays repeated Items in Windows 8 Surface

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

One of my question and i wonder sometimes is, how ComboBox displays Items repeatedly in Windows 8 Surface. I have the Collection which is bound to ComboBox in Windows Store apps. I checked this bounded collections in Simulator and Local machine debugging. It is working fine in both the cases.

But when i bring the same app to Windows 8 surface to test it, this ComboBox displays Items repeatedly in its drop down. Am i anything missing here?. Could you please anyone help me on this to disable this option ?

Comment: Combo box has carousal panel as item panel so it touch devices combo box will show items as loop of items.

Comment: I expect the option to disable this repetitive display . One wonder is, How this looping is not occurred when i test it with Simulator and Local Machine. Anything missed ?

Comment: No, I can see in simulator if you choose touch mode.

Comment: I tried in Simulator also. It does not have any looping in DropDown of ComboBox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combo box uses `CarouselPanel` as `ItemsPanel`, you need to change to `StackPanel`, then your problem will be solved.

Here's detailed blog regarding that. I hope it might help you.

[Windows 8′s combobox and the carouselpanel](http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2013/04/12/windows-8s-combobox-and-the-carouselpanel/)

[winRT ComoBox: suggestions to replace it with standard dropdown behavior?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/b07e671f-7a3c-4f00-9104-cdf6df645fcb)